# Some of my columns get missing when I use df.corr in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

Here is my code:

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('death_regression2.csv')
data3 = data.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex = True)  


plt.figure(figsize=(90,90)) 
corr = data3.corr()

print(np.shape(list(corr)))
print(np.shape(data3))
```

---

(135,)
(4909, 204)

So before I use the correlation function, the total number of parameters was 204(number of the columns)
but after using data3.corr(), some parameters go missing, reduced to 135.

How do check the correlation between all columns in the data?

Comment: Can you check the data type of your columns?

Comment: @FChm I checked the datatype and noticed that it has a mixed form of int64 and object. The object parameters seem to be missing! And thank you for the comment!

Comment: If my answer doesn't address your question, could you potentially add an example of an int column and a  object column?

Comment: my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51877292/pandas-method-corr-use-not-all-features) to might be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without seeing any additional data to understand why you are missing columns, we will have to inspect what [`pd.DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) does.

As the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) outlines it computes the pairwise correlations of columns. Because you specified no arguments is uses the default method and calculate [*Pearson's r*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient), which measures the linear correlation between two variables (X, Y) and can take values between -1 and 1 corresponding to an exact  negative linear correlation to an exact positive linear correlation and all the values in between, with 0 being no correlation (i.e., the plot of X against Y is a random and a linear regression would fit a flat slope).

For non-numerical variables, there is no concept of correlation (at least within the context of Pearson's r and this answer) and `pd.DataFrame.corr` simply ignores non-numerical (i.e., non-float or non-integer values) and drops these columns, explaining why you have less columns.

If your dropped values are in fact numerical but stored (for example) as strings, you probably need to convert them before calling `.corr()`.

As an example:

```
x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)
x_scaled = x*6 
cat = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 
       'six','seven', 'eight', 'nine', 'ten']

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'x_s':x_scaled, 'cat':cat})

df.corr()
```

returns:

```
        x            y          x_s
 x   1.000000    -0.470699    1.000000
 y  -0.470699     1.000000   -0.470699
x_s  1.000000    -0.470699    1.000000
```

which is our correlation matrix but our non-numerical column (`cat`) has been dropped.

If you plot the different numerical variables against each other you get the below plot:

[image: pearsons_r_example]

which helps highlight the different correlations: by chance there is a negative linear correlation between `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
like you mentioned, the numbers on certain missing columns had the format of objects.
After changing it into numeric using df.convert_objects(convert_numeric = True), I could figure out all correlation coefficients! 
Thank you for a kind answer!