# Matrix from corr() method isn't showing all features

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've used the corr() method on a dataframe and the resulting matrix is missing features. I've looked at [a similar question asked perviously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980417/some-of-my-columns-get-missing-when-i-use-df-corr-in-pandas), but it hasn't fixed my issue. The columns in question are of the type int64. These features are showing up when I use pairplot from seaborn.

The missing features are all converted categorical values (i.e. the name of the feature/column is "Fantasy Genre" and it takes a value of 0 or 1, depending on whether the work fits into the fantasy genre).

EDIT:

Here are the columns of the database:

```
Domestic Rank             908 non-null int64
Release                   908 non-null object
Distributor               908 non-null object
Rating                    424 non-null object
Domestic_Earnings         908 non-null int64
International_Earnings    908 non-null int64
Runtime                   894 non-null float64
Release_Date              908 non-null datetime64[ns]
Genres                    908 non-null object
Biography                 908 non-null int64
Documentary               908 non-null int64
Drama                     908 non-null int64
History                   908 non-null int64
Music                     908 non-null int64
Film-Noir                 908 non-null int64
Romance                   908 non-null int64
Crime                     908 non-null int64
Mystery                   908 non-null int64
Musical                   908 non-null int64
Thriller                  908 non-null int64
Comedy                    908 non-null int64
Action                    908 non-null int64
War                       908 non-null int64
Sci-Fi                    908 non-null int64
News                      908 non-null int64
Family                    908 non-null int64
Short                     908 non-null int64
Reality-TV                908 non-null int64
Adult                     908 non-null int64
Sport                     908 non-null int64
Adventure                 908 non-null int64
Animation                 908 non-null int64
Horror                    908 non-null int64
Fantasy                   908 non-null int64
Western                   908 non-null int64
```

Running `movies2019.drop(columns=['Domestic Rank','Domestic_Earnings']).corr()` results in [this matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IULIL.png). I would've expected it to include the individual genres as well.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your code and the input/output? Thanks.

Comment: @LiamFiddler edited. thanks for the tip.

Comment: So I reran the jupyter notebook today and the matrix is showing all correlations... I'm working on limited time right now so not going to look a gift horse in the mouth. I might go back and figure out what happened later.

Answer (score 2):

That may be because it's unusual to calculate a correlation coefficient between two binary categorical variables. Think about the scatterplot for two such variables: It would have points only in the four corners.

A more common (if ultimately equivalent) approach for such data is to look at the pairwise contingency tables, e.g for Biography and Documentary:

```
              Documentary
              0     1
Biography 0   800   45
          1   55    8
```

This would tell you that 800 entries were classified as neither, 8 as both, and there were 45 Documentaries that weren't Biographies, and 55 Biographies that weren't Documentaries. Now to see if there is a correlation between the two categories (i.e. if the probability that something is a Documentary depends on whether it's a Biography and vice versa), you can do a chi-square contingency test on this table.

There is a function for this in SciPy: [scipy.stats.chi2_contingency()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html)

To get the contingency tables, you can use [pandas.crosstab()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html)

Comment: Good explaination. One could also use fisher test to measure independence in contingency tables. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.fisher_exact.html